# Is there any way to make the Eclipse debugger only show non-inherited Java variables?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm working with a Java class Foo that extends JFrame.  When I use the debugger in Eclipse Luna, I see dozens of inherited instance variables that I don't care about.  Is there any way to hide them and only show the instance variables explicitly declared within Foo?

[image: screen capture from Eclipse]

Comment: Not the optimal solution, but if you're only looking for a few values and you're always looking in the same context - you can use the "watch" view instead.

Answer (score 0):

No. It's theoretically possible, but there's no setting for this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  By "theoretically possible", do you mean that someone could create a plugin that did that, or something else?